# Storing date in dd-mm-yyyy format for react state with input type as date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

I wanted it to get dd-mm-yyyy rather than yyyy-mm-dd while saving in state and sending it to firestore database, is there any solutions?

```
state = { date: '' }

handleChange = event => {
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        })
    }

    <Step1
   handleChange={this.handleChange}
   date={this.state.date} 
/>

<input
    className="form-control"
    id="Date"
    name="date"
    type="date"
    value={props.date}
    onChange={props.handleChange}
/>
```

Comment: This is a bad idea. Data storage should be a *standard* date format, not a locale date format representation.

Comment: okay i didn't know about that, thank you! @str

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your case, you can do it in a one-liner

```
date = date.split("-").reverse().join("-");
```